# Problems with network connection in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, virtualbox

This question may seem a duplicate, but I guess it's not. I've read tens and tens of articles and answers, not only on this site, but I didn't find anything.
I use Kali Linux in VirtualBox, I installed the Virtual Machine Version, so I did no configuration.
Here are the outputs of some commands I found on the web:
`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:00:27:0e:34:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 248  bytes 20952 (20.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 248  bytes 20952 (20.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`service network-manager start`:

```
Failed to start network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.
```

`lspci | grep -i network` doesn't output nothing.
When I hover the network icon it gives the message "No network connection" and this screenshot:

[image]

shows what happens when I click it.
If you want the output of other command ask and I'll edit the question.

Comment: While it's tagged linux and kali-linux, the problem is probably on the host and the virtualbox configuration to pass-through an actual physical device so it will be available in the VM (wireless is never easy to handle, and has limitations due to its nature that don't exist with Ethernet). What makes you think you should find a wireless device here?

Comment: I just want to connect Kali to my WiFi, I posted the output of those commands just because in another similar question they were requested by the users.

Comment: But it's not about Kali, it's about making a wireless device appear in the virtual machine, even before Kali boots. If at least `lspci | grep -i network` showed the hint of a Wireless device existing...?

Comment: You might want to clarify if you want to connect kali via WiFi, which would make it necessary to passthru a network adapter, or if you just want to connect kali to your network, which would make it necessary to bridge or NAT your host machines network to the VM

Comment: @mashuptwice I misspelled the question, I want to connect it to my network.

Comment: It looks like you've not set up a network in VBox. This isn't anything to do with Kali

Comment: @roaima I actually did, I've set up a network when I installed VirtualBox.

Comment: My mind-reading isn't too hot today. What sort of network did you set up? If it's NAT did you enable DHCP? If it's bridged is there a DHCP server on the network somewhere? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/694524/edit) to include this information

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @A.B, can you run `lspci | grep -iE 'network|ethernet|wireless' to confirm that the network has been set up?